# Port Java library to iOS using GWT

Tags: java, javascript, ios, gwt-exporter

I've created the code to sign bitcoin transactions using bitcoinj lib. I need the same functionality on all kind of devices: browser, server-side, android, ios, windows phone. I made some research and found GWT-export tool. So I can create pure JS lib and use it on all kind of devices.

However there are some controversial opinions about using it.
E.g. [Java on iOS and Windows Phone using GWT](http://doduck.com/java-ios-windows-phone/)
In conclusion they said it's not possible to run produced code on iOS.

Is it possible to create JS lib from Java and run it without any Java stuff on all kind of devices with only javascript engine?

Comment: "In conclusion they said it's not possible to run produced code on iOS. " then the article must have changed in the time period where you read it and the time period where I read it, because it doesn't say any such thing in the conclusion. Its simply a tutorial on how to use GWT for some basic things and some appropriate remarks on limitations. GWT was not built to translate Java applications to Javascript, it was designed to be able to build JS applications using Java as the starting point.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the conclusion. Thanks